# Entity Framework связь один ко многим

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Решил попрактиковаться с БД и установить связь один ко многим, не понимаю что не так делаю.

```
class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int TeamId { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
    }
```

Строка подключения:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TeamContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Teamstest;Integrated Security=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Контекст данных:

```
class TeamContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

Проблема в том что когда я достаю объекты типа Player из базы, свойство Team в этих объектах равна null

Comment: а почему не public virtual Team Team {get;set;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю что Вы идете по пути code first, то есть создаете базу из модели. В таком случае следует class Player поправить следующим образом

```
class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    //явно указываем что это ключ для записи в таблице Team 
    [ForeignKey("Team ")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Далее, если у вас в базе в таблице данные лежат правильно и ключ TeamId там заполнен то причиной того что Вы видите null вместо заполненного свойства Team может быть ленивая загрузка(lazy loading). Если вы получаете данные таким образом

```
TeamContext db = new TeamContext();
var Players = db.Players.ToList();
```

Вы получаете поле Team не заполненным до прямого к нему обращения, например

```
foreach (var Player in Players)
   Console.WriteLine(Player.Team.Name);
```

В этом случае фреймворк генерирует отдельный запрос и заполняет необходимые данные.

Если же Вы хотите получить поле Team заполненным на этапе выгрузки из базы объекта Player то следует воспользоваться методом прямой загрузки (eager loading).

```
TeamContext db = new TeamContext();
var Players = db.Players
                .Include(x => x.Team)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Поправил класс Player, при обращении поля на прямую выдаёт исключение `NullReferenceException` - это после ленивой загрузки. Последний подход мне не удалось использовать, т.к. не компилируется из-за ошибки: `Невозможно преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" к типу "string", поскольку он не является делегатом`

Comment: @Алексей нужно указать using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало используя последний подход